# Ant Design Upload get file content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, antd

I am using the Ant Design Upload component. Is there a way I can get the content of the selected file as a string in JavaScript in order to display it on the page?

Ideally, I would like to access `file.data` or something.

```
<Upload
    accept=".txt, .csv"
    showUploadList={false}
    beforeUpload={(file, fileList) => {
        // Access file content here and do something with it
        console.log(file);

        // Prevent upload
        return false;
    }}
>
    <Button>
        <Icon type="upload" /> Click to Upload
    </Button>
</Upload>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Heavily inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55279833/6058120) answer from [Shreyans Shrivastav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9669724/shreyans-shrivastav) but modified to better suit what has been asked. You can use a `FileReader` to read the content of the file:

```
<Upload
    accept=".txt, .csv"
    showUploadList={false}
    beforeUpload={file => {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = e => {
            console.log(e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);

        // Prevent upload
        return false;
    }}
>
    <Button>
        <Icon type="upload" /> Click to Upload
    </Button>
</Upload>;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
const { Upload, message, Button, Icon, } = antd;

const props = {
  name: 'file',
  action: '//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/',
  headers: {
    authorization: 'authorization-text',
  },
  onChange(info) {
    if (info.file.status !== 'uploading') {
       let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
           console.log(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsText(info.file.originFileObj);
    }
    if (info.file.status === 'done') {
      message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully`);
    } else if (info.file.status === 'error') {
      message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
    }
  },
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Upload {...props}>
    <Button>
      <Icon type="upload" /> Click to Upload
    </Button>
  </Upload>,
  mountNode
);
```

Please check [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaXpbW?editors=0010#anon-login)

Comment: This program just prints the content of the file. But how can i get the content instead of printing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement to view the uploaded file. I followed the below approach.

```
const { Dragger } = Upload;
state = {
  document: [],
};

onChangeDragger = (event) => {
  event.fileList.forEach((list) => {
    if (list.uid === event.file.uid) {
      list.url = URL.createObjectURL(event.file);
    }
  });
  if (event.fileList.length <= 1) {
    this.setState({ document: event });
  }
};

<Form formName="sample" form={form}>
  <Form.Item name={REQUEST_MODEL.document}>
    {form.getFieldDecorator("document", { initialValue: {} })(
      <Dragger
        accept={ACCEPTABLE_FILE_TYPES.join(", ")}
        name="file"
        fileList={document.fileList}
        showUploadList={false}
        onChange={(event) => this.onChangeDragger(event)}
        multiple={false}
        disabled={document?.fileList?.length >= 1}
      >
        <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
          <UploadCloudIcon />
        </p>
      </Dragger>
    )}
  </Form.Item>
</Form>;

{
  document?.fileList &&
    document.fileList.map((file) => (
      <div key={file.uid} className={Styles.uploadList}>
        <div className={Styles.uploadFileName}>
          <a href={file.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            {file.name}
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    ));
}
```

The idea of the approach is to use a state and insert the file inside the document state. In the onChangeDragger function when  a file is inserted into the state we need to create the url(i.e using URL.createObjectURL(event.file)) and append the url of the file into the state. By accessing the url we can display the content of the file.
The above approach worked for me.